# Unnecessary release in setter

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, accessor

There are many examples of setter how we should do it, for example:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)newFoo
{
    if (foo != newFoo)
    {
        [foo release];//??
        foo = [newFoo retain];
    }
}
```

I'm understanding that we need to release prev value and then assign new one with retain, that's how documentation say us to do, but I can't understand for what we should release, if assigning foo = [newFoo retain]; will make foo just a new value with newFoo's current retain counter, and if even foo's retain counter was 5 before, it will become newFoo's + 1, or I something miss and understand incorrect. Why we can't just do:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)newFoo
{
     if (foo != newFoo)
     {
         foo = [newFoo retain];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C works with pointers (everything is a pointer).

When you perform `retain` or `release` you are not doing that on the reference/pointer (your variable name) but on the actual object itself.

That is why we need to release the old object (because we have finished with it), and point our variable to the new one, (then increase its `retain` count, so it doesn't get removed by something else).

Hope that makes sense

Comment: oh 10x, i understand. In fact we need to release not var but cell of memory

Answer (score 0):

foo is a pointer (a memory address) pointing to an NSString object stored in memory. When this setter function starts, there are two NSString objects in memory: one is being pointed at and retain by foo, and the other is being passed in as an argument. Each object has its own retain count.

foo == newFoo tells the pointer to stop pointing at the old NSString, and start pointing at the new one.

If you didn't release the first object before changing the pointer, it would cause a memory leak. The old object wouldn't have anything pointing to it (so it doesn't exist as far as your program knows), but it's retain count will never reach 0 and get deallocated because it's still being retained.